# print lines where the third character is a digit

Tags: bash, grep

for example our bash script's name is masodik and there is a text.txt with these lines:

```
qwer
qw2qw
12345
qwert432
```

Then I write ./masodik text.txt and i got

```
qw2qw
12345
```

I tried it many ways and I dont know why this is not working

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in read u ; do
    echo $i $u | grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]'
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep -E '^.{2}[0-9]' text.txt 
qw2qw
12345
```

, and in script it could be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -E '^.{2}[0-9]' "$1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Please help me a little bit more, how can I add this in a script? With a for or a while?

Comment: I don't sure I understart the question proprely.... You don't really need the cycles (`for` or `while`). Even with multiple input files (as command line parameters): `grep ^..[0-9] $@` or `cat $@ | grep ^..[0-9]` (output will be different). The same is dobale with cycle. but it is odd: `for f in $@ ; do grep ^..[0-9] $f ; done`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in read u ; do
    echo $i $u | grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]'
done
```

...is that the `for` syntax is wrong:

- `read u` is treated as a word list.  So the `$u` variable is never set, so `$u` stays empty.
- The `for` loop will run twice -- the 1st time `$i` will be set to the string *"read"*, the 2nd time `$i` will be set to the string *"u"*.  Since neither string contains a number, the `grep` returns nothing.
- The code *never* reads *text.txt*.

See [*Sasha Khapyorsky*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60575543/6136214) for actual working code.

---

If for some odd reason all external utils, (`grep`, `awk`, *etc.*), are forbidden, this pure *POSIX* code would work:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read u ; do
    case "$u" in
        [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]*) echo "$u" ;; 
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me how to put that in a script? I have to make a variable for the txt, and I don't know how to make it

Comment: @avon016g Just use `grep`... or see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

To print lines whose third character is a digit:

```sh
grep ^..[0-9] text.txt
```

`^` matches the start of the line. The dot `.` matches any character. `[0-9]` matches any digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk` quite easily as well:

```
awk '/^..[0-9]/' file
```

**Result**

With your input in `file`:

```
$ awk '/^..[0-9]/' file
qw2qw
12345
```

(`sed` works as well, `sed -n '/^..[0-9]/p' file`)

Answer (score 0):

If perl is installed into the system then shell script will look like

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -e 'print if /^.{2}\d/' text.txt
```